# RichTextBox CtrlI

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in .NET WinForms.  I have been hooking up hot keys with KeyUp.  Everything is working fine, except for CtrlI.  By the time my handler gets its turn, the selection has been replaced with a '\t'.  I turned off ShortcutsEnabled, but it didn't make any difference.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyRtb : RichTextBox {
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == (Keys.I | Keys.Control)) {
      // Do your stuff
      return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, keyData);
  }
}
```